# How to use local images as background with gotty?

Tags: css, shell, termux

It is possible to use local images, I have tried the following ways but none have worked :(

```
 background_image = "url(https://i.ibb.co/DknqgWf/test.png)"  // This one works
 background_image = "url(~/termux/gotty/wallpapers/wallpaper-1.png)"
 background_image = "url(./termux/gotty/wallpapers/wallpaper-1.png)"
 background_image = "url(/data/data/com.termux/files/home/termux/gotty/wallpapers/wallpaper-1.png)"
```

The doc says it's a css property, so it should work but it doesn't :(
version : 1.0.1
SO: Android

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
background_image = "url(file:///data/data/com.termux/files/home/termux/gotty/wallpapers/wallpaper-1.png)"
```

maybe only two // wherer I have three /// - but posix should always squash too many / to one.

GL